# Insert rows from textarea?

Tags: php, html

The first Page called index.html got an input for notifier and textarea named list this text area where we put links.

```
<form method="POST" action="M_Save.php">
<b>Notifier:</b><br><input type="text" name="ntfr" class="ntfr" maxlength="30" >
<b>Domains: </b><br><textarea type="text" name="list" class="list" style=" width: 452px; min-width: 452px; max-width: 452px;" ></textarea><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="btn"><br><br>
</form>
```

The second page is M_Save.php wich save all the information in the database so the code is

```
function get_domain($urli)
                {
                 $pieces = parse_url($urli);
                 $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
                 if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
                     return $regs['domain'];
                     }
                     return false;
                }
                $ntfr = $_POST['ntfr'];
                $url = $_POST['list'];
                $notifier_name = htmlspecialchars($ntfr);
                $urlo = get_domain($url); 
                $domaine_notr = htmlspecialchars($url);
                $client_ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $server_ip = gethostbyname($urlo);
                $html = file_get_contents($url);
                $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10);
                $myFile = "../Mirror/".$random.".php";
                $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
                fwrite($fh, $html);
                fclose($fh);
                $mirror_link = "Mirror/?id=".$random."";
                $state = "onhold";
                $date = date("m.d.Y");
                $sql="INSERT INTO fallaga_tbl (notifier_name, domaine_notr, server_ip, client_ip, mirror_link, state, date)
                VALUES ('$notifier_name', '$domaine_notr', '$server_ip', '$client_ip', '$mirror_link', '$state', '$date')";
                require("../connecta.php");
               $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                if(! $retval )
                {
                    die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                echo "1 record added <br> <a href=\"NOTIFY.php\">Back</a>";
```

I want that all of these hapend with every link in the text area to be saved in database with notifier name and the other information,  then the script complete to the otherlink. 
Can someone help me ?

Comment: You are a bit vague... can you provide some examples of what you put in and what you want saved into the database?

Comment: Look this is a exemple 
in the input named ntfr let's put "Màh Di"
and for the textarea let's put this list 
"http://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.facebook.com
http://www.youtube.com/"

Comment: And you want what... to split all the URLs and instrt them along with Mah Di in the database?

Comment: Exactly .. i want every url of them in one row with Màh Di

Comment: How are you separating the URLs? with spaces?

Comment: no one url in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will not write the whole code for you, but set you on the right path.

You got these inputs:

```
<b>Notifier:</b><br><input type="text" name="ntfr" class="ntfr" maxlength="30" >
<b>Domains: </b><br><textarea type="text" name="list" class="list" style=" width: 452px; min-width: 452px; max-width: 452px;" ></textarea><br>
```

On the file that handles your post in php, you need to do this:

```
$notifier = (isset($_POST['ntfr']) ? $_POST['ntfr'] : 'Not Defined';
$urls = (isset($_POST['list']) ? $_POST('list'):'';
$urls = explode("\n",$urls);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $url = trim($url);
    mysql_query("insert into... {$notifier},{$url});
}
```

Docs: http://php.net/explode and http://php.net/trim